# Send html tag with CActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I have a form that create with CActiveForm Widget.with jquery i create textbox in this     widget form but when i submit the form these fields does not send.what should i do?

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'event-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
   'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
));
echo $form->textField($model,'title',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45));
// missing php tag?>
<input type="text" name="lname"/>
<?php // missing php tag
$this->endWidget();
// missing php tag
?>
```

Comment: your model naming is incorrect, check generated html by yii and try to make it like them

Comment: i generate <input type="text" name="lname"/> with jquery,the cactiveform dose not submit them,because i think CAciveForm submit input with this style:  $form->textField($model,'title',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45));

Comment: i declare lname field in my model an is safe

Comment: i found that,i add my modelName at the name attribute of my input like this:name="My_Model[lname]"

Comment: beche meshadom:-)to bache kojayi?damet garm dada

Comment: manam mashadam! koja kar mikoni?

Comment: jaye sabtei nistam,projei kar mikonam ba jahaye mokhtalef.shoma kojayi dadash?

Comment: blog e mano nega kon, darmorede yii hast: http://blog.tinybyte.ir

Comment: merc,datepicker jalali darid shoma?az jalalidatepicker estfade kardam vali dorost kar nemikone!!salao miladi miyare,maharo shamsi va tagvimam bar asas miladi tanzim mikone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suppose you have a class named Post and an attribute title,

then you need to make input like this

```
 <input type="text" name="Post[title]"/>
```

or

```
 echo CHtml::textField('Post[title]' , '');
```

see we have attribute inside post array, that is what yii is looking for attributes